# Como escribir un IF para saber si session_start esta corriendo

Tags: javascript, php, html

quisiera saber como es la sintaxis del `if();` para saber si `session_start();` esta activo.

Busqué esto, pero no me funciono:

```
 if (session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
             //si no hay sesion, pues que imprima esta etiqueta
             echo "<a style='background-color: gray'> inicia sesion</a>";
            }else{ //si hay una sesion iniciada, que imprima esta y que inicie la sesion
                               session_start();
                    $correo = $_SESSION["id"];

                    $sql ="select * from usuario where Correo = '".$correo."'";
                    $res=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
  
                    $rows=$res->fetch_assoc();
                    $num_res=$res->num_rows;
                    $nombre = $rows["Nombre"];

                      echo "<a style='background-color: green'> tu usuario es: '".$nombre."'</a>"; 

            }
```

Comment: ¿Intentaste usando [`PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.session-status.php)?

Comment: no se nada de php pero con solo poner PHP_SESSION en google accedo a php.net y esta esto: session_status() se usa para devolver el estado de la sesión actual, estos son los valores devueltos
    PHP_SESSION_DISABLED si las sesiones están deshabilitadas.
    PHP_SESSION_NONE si las sesiones están habilitadas, pero no existe ninguna.
    PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE si las sesiones están habilitadas, y existe una.
con eso creo lo solucionas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que estás confundiendo las sesiones de PHP (navegador) con las de tu proyecto (usuarios):

1. PHP: Se requiere que ejecutes `session_start()` para crear una *cookie* que usará para asociar las siguientes peticiones desde el mismo navegador como un mismo origen (una sesión)
2. Tu proyecto: Teniendo la sesión iniciada, entonces puedes crear variables en `$_SESSION` para identificar al usuario que está realizando la petición

Entonces, si en tu proyecto estás llevando control de usuarios, debes inicializar sesiones con `session_start()` antes de enviar cualquier salida al navegador y sin importar si el usuario ya ingresó sus credenciales o no.

#### ¿Cómo identificar usuarios en tu proyecto?

Primero necesitas el formulario de ingreso y crear variables de sesión para saber que ingresó correctamente:

```
<?php
// Esta línea debe aparecer una sola vez y antes de enviar cualquier cosa al navegador
session_start();
$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$password = $_POST['password];
// Después de verificar que el usuario y la contraseña son correctos
// Creas las variables de sesión
$_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
```

Luego, en cualquier otra página de tu proyecto donde se requiera que el usuario haya iniciado sesión:

```
<?php
// Recuerda, siempre antes de cualquier salida y solo una vez
session_start();
// Verificar que hay sesión iniciada el signo de admiración implica negación
if(!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
    echo 'No has iniciado sesión';
    // Aquí el resto de lógica para usuarios sin sesión
} else {
    echo 'Ya iniciaste sesión';
    // Aquí el resto de lógica para usuarios con sesión
}
```

Comment: gracias, me sirvio. Y en efecto, estaba confundiendo las sesiones del navegador con los datos en la cookie $_session de mi base de datos